# I have to pass the cookies into another request using selenium web driver sampler in jmeter..I have to kept alive each user's until the end of test

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have 2 request (login,logout) under 2 different transactions.

When I have login in the page i am just pass the url of login and username, password.i am able to do the login using selenium webserver sampler

But when i tried to logout the page. I have passed the URL of logout. But it goes to do the login page..

1. I don't know why it is again back to login page...
2. I need to get cookies from login page...
3. I have to pass the cookies into logout page and make connection alive for each user's..

I have to collect the results for login and logout separately..

Could you please tell me how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

1. If your WebDriver Samplers are in the same [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) you don't need to do anything.
2. If they're in different Thread Groups - put them under the same Thread Group and remove the other one
3. If for any reason you want to have them in different Thread Groups you could use [WebDriver.Options](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Options.html) for getting and setting the cookies something like:

   - In first Thread Group:

     ```
     props.put('cookies_' + ctx.getThreadNum(), WDS.browser.manage().getCookies())
     ```
   - In second Thread Group:

     ```
     props.get('cookies_' + ctx.getThreadNum()).each { cookie -> WDS.browser.manage().addCookie(cookie) }
     ```

   More information on what do these `props` and `ctx` mean: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)